# In a Request header in C# .NET core, how can I check if a key has multiple in input?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, request, httprequest

I have this key in the HTTP request

```
Request.Headers["Key"]
```

It can have a single value or multiple values 
Example

```
key: "xl"


key: ["xx", "xl"]
```

How can I check if it there is multiple or input or a single input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check it by using the following function:

```
private bool IsSingleHeader(IHeaderDictionary headers, string key) 
{
    return headers.ContainsKey(key) && headers[key].Count() == 1;
}
```

Regards,